# Quick Performance on Large DB (>100M primitives) with limited RAM

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, heap-size

I'm working on a project involving using data from PubMed to find connections between MeSH Terms and Articles they're mentioned in. The Neo4j DB I've built for it contains ~11M nodes and ~100M relationships and I'm experiencing extremely slow query times (30 min or greater) in a lot of cases, including queries as simple as `"Match (a:MeSHTerm)<-[:Mentions]-(b:Article) WHERE a.name="Calcimycin" RETURN b"` (i.e. just looking for all nodes with a Mentions relationship to the node w/ name Calcimycin). This is all being done on a university blade running Ubuntu 12.04 with a very limited amount of RAM (according to the free command, 3G of RAM, 2 of which are in use by applications other than neo4j). Right now, the wrapper config sets the minimum java heap size at 16mb and the max at 64 mb (though the difference in used memory when neo4j is running and when it is not is 1G; any explanation on where the rest of that GB is being used?).

1. I'm not sure how much more I can expand the heap size without
   butting into the swap file, since free tells me I'm using all of the
   available RAM when neo4j is running and
2. if we need to expand to a stronger system with more RAM in order to
   obtain reasonable query times. Any suggestions would be much
   appreciated, and I'm happy to clarify wherever I can, though I'm
   still new to working with Ubuntu in general.

Update:
After adding an index on the label MeSHTerm, query time has improved to on-average ~11s, based on 100 randomized tests of the query. Anything more I can do? I'd love to bring it down to sub-second times, as this is eventually going to be a web-based tool.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please use formatting when you post qtn/ans

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't mention that you have an index on

```
:`MeSH Term`(name)
```

I'm going to recommend that you create one:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :`MeSH Term`(name);
```

Also, I recommend you avoid using spaces in your labels.

Comment: Haha, yes, I figured out the issue with spaces in the name the hard way. Once I've created the index, do I need to do anything to populate it? Should I run a query over all the nodes with that label?

Comment: It will populate in the background.